# How can I convert a FM discriminated signal to binary data using software

Tags: audio, digital

I currently have FM discriminated data in a .wav file.
[image]
How can I convert it to binary data (+0.5 == high bit, -0.5 == low bit) given a baud rate.

Comment: Do you want to know that for a particular type of application (like a matlab application, C application, Java ...) or just want to know an algorithm to do it ?

Comment: @Loufylouf I want to know if a some software already exists for this task. Currently, I can get the signed amplitude using multimon-ng DUMPCSV. It would be good if there is a software that can process the CSV output ( Time, amplitude) pairs.